# How to check which user Phusion Passenger chooses to run node.js?

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor, passenger

What is the best practice for using Phusion Passenger with a version of node installed my nvm?

---

In [this tutorial](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial) on using Passenger to run a Meteor app, I read:

> [Y]our Meteor application is run as ... the owner of the
>   main.js file (when deploying a Meteor bundle), unless you configure it
>   otherwise. Of course you still have to make sure that each of your
>   applications is owned by another user.

Meteor 1.6 works with Node.js v8.8.1, so I have used nvm to install node. I created a special `meteor` user to run the nvm installation of node and nvm. Node was therefore installed at `/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin/node`, and `/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin/` was added to the $PATH variable for my `meteor` user. As a result, calling `node -v` as the `meteor` user showed that v8.8.1 was installed and accessible.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/nginx/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html#build-package) to deploy my Meteor app to my server.

As the `meteor` user from within the `bundle/programs/server` directory, I ran `npm install --production`. I made `meteor` the owner of everthing inside `bundle/`.

I had expected that Passenger would launch node as the `meteor` user, and that everything would run smoothly. Instead, Passenger showed a useful alert page, apologising that "something went wrong".

To work around this, I created a symlink at `/usr/bin/node` to point at `/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin/node`, and now Passenger was happy to launch the bundled app.

This suggests to me that Passenger was **not** running `main.js` as the `meteor` user. Or is there another reason why the `meteor` user was not able to see its own version of node?

The quote above suggests that it is possible to configure which user Passenger uses. How do I do that?

In a nutshell: what is the official Passenger method for working with a version of node installed by nvm?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set the version of node to the full path to the nvm node: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--nodejs-nodejs

As for the user-switching, you can set the log-level to 7 (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--log-level-log_level) in order to debug that and either go through the startup logs yourself or post them here.